# Batch script to generate a csv file containing the subfolder name and size of a particular log file w.r.t each user

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder named Folder1. Inside Folder1 have some sub-folders (a,b,c,d,e...) Inside each sub-folder there is a log file with same name across all the sub-folders (test.log). size of each log files are different. I need to generate a csv file containing the sub-folder name and size of a particular log file w.r.t each user.

eg: my output should be

a 180

b 220

c 450

I tried writing a code by searching in Google.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem To put the sub-folder names inside the Folder1 into a text file try.txt

pushd C:\....\Folder1\*
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /ad') do echo %%f >> try.txt
popd


rem To put the values inside a text file(try.txt) into a variable %Build% (but the values are place horizontally with spaces; it is not inserting vertically) 

pushd C:\....\Folder1\try.txt\*
for /f "delims=" %%f in (try.txt) do set Build=!Build!%%f
popd

echo %Build%'\n' >> bb.log
```

My idea was to put the sub-folder names in a text file called try.txt and put the values inside the text files into a vaiable %Build%. then go to the path where the log file is present to get the size. like below.

```
 for /f %%i in ("C:\....\Folder1\%Build%\....\test.log") do set "size=%%~zi" >> output.csv
```

Please help me out as I am new to batch scripting.

How can I modify the same script if conditions are like below.

```js
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\sys.log 

where my output should be:

<username1> sys.log file size (for each usernames under C:\Users) 
<username2> sys.log file size
<username3> sys.log file size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo %~0: error: missing base directory.& exit /b 1)

set files=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "%~1\*"') do set files=!files! %~1\%%i\test.log
for %%i in (!files!) do echo %%i,%%~zi

exit /b 0
```

I've parameterized the base directory on the first argument, so you can call it as follows, assuming you've saved the script as size.bat in the directory just above Folder1:

```
size.bat Folder1
```

**Update:** Let me know if this works:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo %~0: error: missing prefix.& exit /b 1)
if "%~2" equ "" (echo %~0: error: missing suffix.& exit /b 1)

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "%~1\*"') do (
    set infix=%%~i
    set file=%~1\!infix!\%~2
    for %%j in ("!file!") do set size=%%~zj
    echo !infix!,%~nx2,!size!
)

exit /b 0
```

I've parameterized the suffix as well now, and redesigned the first (now only) for loop to fully process each file before moving on to the next file, rather than constructing a space-separated string list of files. This new design has the advantage that spaces in path names (prefix, suffix, or infix) should be handled correctly.

You can call this new script as follows:

```
size.bat C:\Users AppData\Roaming\sys.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Its working fine. but i have one more doubt. how can I modify the same script if conditions are like below. C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\sys.log                      where my output should be                                            <username> sys.log file size (for each usernames under  C:\Users\) Please help

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to present a different approach that uses Powershell.

```
# Easy way
dir C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\sys.log | Select-Object Fullname, Length

# What you asked for
dir c:\users | ForEach-Object{ $_.name + " " +  (dir "$_\AppData\Roaming\sys.log").Length  }
```

If you are just getting started with batch files, take a little time to explore PowerShell. This example isn't too bad for batch files to handle. But I see you dumping data to files just to be processed in later commands. I think you will find a lot of value in the way powershell deals with objects and enumerating collections of things.